# More elements in LinkedList<T> than COUNT property can return in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

The `count` property of `LinkedList<T>`has return type of `int`. What if my `LinkedList<T>` has more elements than `int` can store and want to know the elements in it. Wont it cause an overflow ? I'm asking this because I am given to create a sequence whose upper bound is `10e15`elements it means more elements than an `int` can store and I want to check that a certain value is less than total elements in my `LinkedList<T>` and that certain value can be greater than `int` but still less than the given upper bound.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Create your own list class and use longs, assuming that wont overflow

Comment: @PetSerAI 4GB. I just saw the longCount Property of LinkedList<T>. I guess this answers my question. Should I delete this post ? I guess I was too hasty to ask this question

Comment: @Ahmed.J I can't find any other question about this on SO. Might be worthwhile self-answering this

Comment: On 64-bit system `LinkedListNode` consume at least 25 bytes of data + 16 bytes of CLR header. How much or those you can fit in 4GB?

Comment: @PetSerAI Hmmm Yes, you are correct I totally forgot about that. I guess I have to rethink my problem statement and find a different solution then just creating a very large list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `longCount` extension method for LinkedList in **System.Linq** namespace which return Int64.

**Note:**

As Hans Passant says in the comment that it traverses the whole list having O(n) complexity and its use must be avoided with LinkedLists

Comment: LinkedList does not have a LongCount property.  It is an extension method provided by System.Linq.  You must **never** use it on LinkedList since it requires a full traversal of the list, O(n) complexity.  Excessively expensive when you need the Long, you'll access many gigabytes of memory.